# Index of a element in array using substring

Tags: java, arrays, regex, substring, indexof

I need to get the index of an element in array to be searched:

```
 String[] items = {"One:10.1.22.33", "Two:10.1.21.23", "Three:10.1.21.33", "Four:10.1.21.23", "Five:10.1.22.23"};
 String q = "Two";  //need to find index of element starting with sub-sting "Two"
```

what I tried

Try-1

```
    String temp = "^"+q;    
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(items).indexOf(temp));
```

Try-2

```
items[i].matches(temp)
for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    if(items[i].matches(temp)) System.out.println(i);
}
```

Both are not working as expected.

Comment: `matches` tries to match the entire string. If you want to use `matches` you would have to use `"^" + q + ".*"` or something similar. (You would probably want to wrap `q` in `Pattern.quote` as well.)

Comment: Thankyou its working for items[i].matches but not working for  .indexof

Comment: What do you mean? If you use `temp = "Two.*"` then `1` should be printed. Isn't it? (`String.indexOf` can only be used on a `String`, not a list of strings.)

Comment: Wait, why don't you use a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @aioobe Thanks great info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be better off using [`startsWith(String prefix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) like this:

```
String[] items = {"One:10.1.22.33", "Two:10.1.21.23", "Three:10.1.21.33", "Four:10.1.21.23", "Five:10.1.22.23"};
String q = "Two";  //need to find index of element starting with substring "Two"
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].startsWith(q)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Your first try does not work because you are trying to get the index of the String `^Two` inside your list, but [`indexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) does not accept regular expression.

Your second try does not work because [`matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) works on the entire String, not just on the beginning.

If you are using Java 8, you could write the following code which returns the index of the first item beginning with `"Two"`, or -1 if none was found.

```
String[] items = {"One:10.1.22.33", "Two:10.1.21.23", "Three:10.1.21.33", "Four:10.1.21.23", "Five:10.1.22.23"};
String q = "Two";
int index = IntStream.range(0, items.length).filter(i -> items[i].startsWith(q)).findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we get index without loop ??

Comment: @Ravichandra To get the index, you are going to have to loop. If you are using Java 8, this can be hidden inside a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to implement `LinearSearch` for this but with a twist, you were searching for `substring`. You can try this.

```
String[] items = {"One:10.1.22.33", "Two:10.1.21.23", "Three:10.1.21.33", "Four:10.1.21.23", "Five:10.1.22.23"};
String q= "Two";  //need to find index of element starting with sub-sting "Two"

for (int i = 0; 0 < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].startsWith(q)){
        // item found
        break;
    } else if (i == items.length) {
        // item not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String q= "Five";String pattern = q+"(.*)";
for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
if(items[i].matches(pattern))
 { 
  System.out.println(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: For try-2  you should use  q +"(.*)" . It will provide the index of q with any character

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.